# Proving that $\{\triangle,\cap\}$ and $\{\setminus,\cup\}$ are complete sets of set operations

Tags: measure-theory

In my course of Measure Theory, my professor stated that both of these sets of set operations, $\{\triangle,\cap\}$ and $\{\setminus,\cup\}$, suffice to perform all operations on sets.

I wonder how a proof of this would go. It makes me think of propositional calculus when I wanted to prove that a set of logical connectives was complete. The idea was to show that each of the connectives of a given set could be expressed in terms of smth we knew it was a complete set of connective, for instance $\{\land,\neg \}$.

So of course I know how to express $\{\triangle,\cap\}$ in terms of $\{\setminus,\cup\}$ and vice versa so it suffices to prove that one of these indeed suffices to provide all set operations. But... how does one prove this?

Let's for instance choose to prove this for $\{\triangle,\cap\}$. Intuitively if I draw a Venn diagram with two sets $A$ and $B$ I see that this set of set operations indeed "generates" all possible "partitions" of these sets $A$ and $B$, but how does one rigorously state this?

**Edit:** $A\triangle B=(A\setminus B) \cup( B\setminus A)$

Comment: What operation is $\triangle$? Symmetric difference?

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought it was a standard notion for symmetric difference, i.e. $A\triangle B=(A\setminus B) \cup( B\setminus A)$.

Comment: It's standard, I guess, but not as commonly used as the other three.

Comment: About $\setminus$ -- Do you mean as a binary operation, as in $A \setminus B,$ or can it be used as unary, so that $\setminus A$ would mean the complement of $A$? [If only a binary I don't see how to get complement, but that's maybe easy...]

Comment: I mean as a binary operation. $$A\cup B=(A\triangle B)\triangle(A\cap B)$$
$$A\setminus B=A\triangle(A\cap B)$$

Comment: Did you find a way to get $A'$ from $A$ using $\setminus,\cup$? [Where $A'$ means complement of $A$)] Of course if you can use a universe set $U,$ one has $A'=U \setminus A.$